# Transmission Fail to start using service

Tags: ubuntu, bittorrent

I installed `transmission-daemon` by follow a tutorial, and `s3fs` as its completed folder. At first, it came a error about failed to set buffer, after I search over web and disable the `utp`, but it started to fail with another reason. `sudo service transmission-daemon status` give me the following error:

```
● transmission-daemon.service - Transmission BitTorrent Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Tue 2016-04-19 23:29:09 UTC; 31s ago
  Process: 7045 ExecStart=/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
 Main PID: 7045 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
   Status: "Idle."

Apr 19 23:29:08 transmission systemd[1]: Starting Transmission BitTorrent Daemon...
Apr 19 23:29:08 transmission systemd[1]: Started Transmission BitTorrent Daemon.
Apr 19 23:29:09 transmission transmission-daemon[7045]: transmission-daemon: res_query.c:262: __libc_res_nquery: Assertion `(hp != ((void *)0)) && (hp2 != ((void *)0))' failed.
Apr 19 23:29:09 transmission systemd[1]: transmission-daemon.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
Apr 19 23:29:09 transmission systemd[1]: transmission-daemon.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 19 23:29:09 transmission systemd[1]: transmission-daemon.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

However, the `transmission-daemon` will start with no problem if I run `transmission-daemon -f --log-error --log-info --log--debug`. Moreover, if I use `service` command to start it, the access permission will change from `770` to `300`, reason unknown. Can someone help me to solve this problem.

### NOTE

The machine I'm using is Ubuntu 15.04, enabled TCP-LP, hosted at Vultr

Articles I had read please go http://pastebin.com/f9sGPRk6

### EDIT

Now I rebuild the whole system with the same configurations in Ubuntu 14.04, all things go fine, no errors. May be this error only happens on 15.04?

Comment: If you run in a terminal the command `ldd --version`, which version is reported?

Comment: @Hewbot The command reported version 2.21